# create `KafkaServer` from Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

I am trying to start a Kafka server form Java

Specifically, how can I translate [this line](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/cb674e5487f3f56647546b323dfe4fd45ccf0186/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/KafkaServerStartable.scala#L33) of Scala into a line of Java?

```
  private val server = new KafkaServer(serverConfig, kafkaMetricsReporters = reporters)
```

I can create the serverConfig easily, but I can't seem to be able to create the `kafkaMetricsReporters` parameter.

Note: I can create a `KafkaServerStartable` but I would like to create a normal `KafkaServer` to avoid the JVM exiting in case of error.

Apache Kafka version 0.11.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `kafkaMetricsReporters` parameter is a scala `Seq`.

You can either:

1. Create a Java collection and convert it into a Seq:

   You need to import `scala.collection.JavaConverters`:

   ```
   List<KafkaMetricsReporter> reportersList = new ArrayList<>();
   ...
   Seq<KafkaMetricsReporter> reportersSeq = JavaConverters.asScalaBufferConverter(reportersList).asScala();
   ```
2. Use `KafkaMetricsReporter.startReporters()` method to create them for you from your configuration:

   As `KafkaMetricsReporter` is a singleton, you need to use the `MODULE` notation to use it:

   ```
   Seq<KafkaMetricsReporter> reporters = KafkaMetricsReporter$.MODULE$.startReporters(new VerifiableProperties(props));
   ```

Also the `KafkaServer` constructor has 2 other arguments that are required when calling it from Java:

- `time` can easily be created using `new org.apache.kafka.common.utils.SystemTime()`
- `threadNamePrefix` is an Option. If you import `scala.Option`, you'll be able to call `Option.apply("prefix")`

Putting it all together:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(...);
KafkaConfig config = KafkaConfig.fromProps(props);
Seq<KafkaMetricsReporter> reporters = KafkaMetricsReporter$.MODULE$.startReporters(new VerifiableProperties(props));
KafkaServer server = new KafkaServer(config, new SystemTime(), Option.apply("prefix"), reporters);
server.startup();
```

Comment: Thanks :)
Two questions: did you mean `reportersList` instead of `reporters`? and where does `new SystemTime()` comes from (which package)?

Comment: Also, it means there will be no reporters, correct? (I am fine with that at the moment, although I will have to create some at some point)

Comment: I've updated my answer. `startReporters()` is probably what you want to use

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can now start a server, although I still pass it an empty reporter seq since I get `Unhandled java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
   kafka.metrics.KafkaMetricsReporter$.MODULE$` . Is `startReporters` a static function?

Comment: I've accepted your answer even if I can't call `KafkaMetricsReporter.startReporters()`. I have a kafka server running, that's the main point here. Thanks!