# Apache KafkaServer create reporters from Java

Tags: java, scala, clojure, apache-kafka

Follow up of [create `KafkaServer` from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990723/create-kafkaserver-from-java)

I am creating a `KafkaServer` from Java (well Clojure really but given a working Java example it is straightforward to translate).

I am not able to pass anything but an empty sequence. How can I write the equivalent of this line in Java?

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/cb674e5487f3f56647546b323dfe4fd45ccf0186/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/KafkaServerStartable.scala#L27

```
val reporters = KafkaMetricsReporter.startReporters(new VerifiableProperties(serverProps))
```

Or, better yet, is there a Java/Clojure API for creating reporters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code I gave you in [create `KafkaServer` from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990723/create-kafkaserver-from-java) should work. I just tried it in 0.11.0.1 (the version you mentioned in the other question) and it works fine.

Full snippet:

```
package main;

import java.util.Properties;
import kafka.metrics.KafkaMetricsReporter;
import kafka.metrics.KafkaMetricsReporter$;
import kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties;
import scala.collection.*;

public class Reporters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Seq<KafkaMetricsReporter> reporters = KafkaMetricsReporter$.MODULE$.startReporters(new VerifiableProperties(props));
    }
}
```